# Does Web Sphere Application Server V8 support JPA 1.0?

Tags: java, jpa, websphere, jpa-2.0

I need to configure WAS 8 with JPA 1.0 because my application use Oracle KODO and it only supports JPA 1.0. I tried to configure using third-party providers and shared libraries but the application server always uses the default persistence provider that is JPA 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed all the steps in the [Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html) and it still picks up the wrong library, you need to open a PMR with IBM support.